# Two Ajax call and returns on the same page

Tags: ajax

I am trying to figure out how to do an ajax call on a php form that is returned from a previous ajax call.

The first call works fine :

```
    function submit() {
    $input = $("#search_bar").val();

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "search.php",
    data: "input="+$input,
    success: function(result) {
        $("#results_box").html(result).show();
    }
});

return false;
```

};

It returns a form with the information requested in the search field. My second ajax call would be referencing the form that the first ajax call returns and this is where I am stuck.

So my question would be : How do I work with a form that has been requested by an ajax call and use ajax again to submit this forms data?

Comment: first you would want to connect the initial ajax call to an event (click of submit button)... and so would be the second ajax call initiated

Comment: Thanks. But my initial issue would be that the form being returned by the first ajax call is within the search.php file. How would I work with that form again with the second ajax call?